# Where is the bundles directory in Eclipse-Liferay IDE?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, liferay-7

I installed the liferay 7 portal/Eclipse IDE and created a liferay workspace in the IDE. The tomcat server is running but how can I see the data folder / hypersonic script in the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a hypersonic script in the Eclipse IDE, please follow these steps:

1. Open your Eclipse-Liferay IDE and at the top, click on:
   Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Other  and select:  "Database Development"
2. Right-click on "Database Connections" and select: "new"
3. Select "HSQLDB" and click on "next"
4. Click on the round icon called "new driver definition" and highlight "HSQLDB JDBC Driver" and then go to the "JAR List" tab.
   Once there, click on Edit JAR/Zip and browse to your liferay7\tomcat-8.0.32\lib\ext folder and select hsqldb.jar
5. Click on "Test Connection" and you'll get "ping succeeded"
6. Click on Finish.
7. On the left side within your Eclipse, you will see the "NEW HSQLDB" connection. Expand it and browse to this location:
   SAMPLE / Catalogs / PUBLIC / schemas /PUBLIC / tables 
   You should be able to see your tables listed here.

You can find a video with the instructions here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHfF9h0-GYY

Hope this helps!